# Bibtex, citations and bibliography not showing

Tags: bibtex

I downloaded this thesis template:

https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/bredele/wyhhrmqjbdbv#.WTgYPcaB3-Z

PROBLEM: Citations not working and bibliography not showing:

> This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2016) The top-level auxiliary
>   file: main.aux I found no \citation commands---while reading file
>   main.aux I found no \bibdata command---while reading file main.aux I
>   found no \bibstyle command---while reading file main.aux (There were 3
>   error messages)

I am using TexMaker.

I tried several solutions online but nothing worked.

Comment: The class expects `biber` not `bibtex` to be used with [`biblatex`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex), hence `bibtex` is not finding the expected contents.  See [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/106162), specifically [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154788/106162) (I would advise you to follow the second suggestion of adding `biber` as a separate user command as reconfiguring Quick build will break it for documents using `bibtex`).

Comment: @DaiBowen thanks I added the `Biber` command same as you told me and it worked. I also tried an alternative by using texmaker that has `Biber` command and it worked too.

Comment: @DaiBowen shall I delete the question due to possible duplication?

Comment: as long as you're running `biber` (via command line would work just as well), the appropriate `bbl` file will be generated (barring errors in the `bib` file) and all should work.

Comment: Marking the question as a duplicate is sufficient (different questions will appear in different search results so it can be helpful) but nothing stops you deleting the question if you wish to.